# iOS(Swift) - autoresizing UILabel in CollectionView cell

Tags: ios, iphone, autoresizingmask

I'm new to autoresizing. All the image and view in collection view cell are ok with autoresizing, but labels don't expand.

Here's for one of label[image]

Result[image]

CA and Comma become one when city label is long. Also both of city label and country label should be 8px away from cell.

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: can you show the screen shot

Comment: All i doing now is in size inspector

Comment: edited @Anbu.Karthik :D

Comment: @Andreas What about height?

Comment: Why I need height? @TonyHan

Comment: no no bro I am not ask this , show the output of the screen  with collectionviewItemAtIndexpath

Comment: sorry bro, now edited @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @Andreas - r u try to set the CA,US label correct , can you show your code , it is single line of code , wil solve your issue

Comment: what do you want to see bro?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Tick the other side also it will also expend your label, and better to use auto layouts, they are bit difficult to learn but you will definitely going to enjoy working in them

Comment: yeah they are kind of amusing but now those label drag me :D
I edited my post with your advise